# Python Selenium get value of TD by ID and class name

Tags: python, selenium

i need to get the DeviceMacAddress - 00:80:91:d5:79:a0

```
<tr id="MACAddrsTrID">
<td class="clsSubHeader" width="45%" nowrap="">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(fnGetLocaleString("101105","MAC Address"));</script>
 MAC Address&nbsp;</td>
<td class="clsBTableElement">
<font id="DeviceMACAddress">00:80:91:d5:79:a0</font>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried

```
themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("MACAddrsTrID").text
print(themac1)


themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("MACAddrsTrID").get_attribute("value")
print(themac1)


themac1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("clsBTableElement").text
print(themac1)


themac1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("clsBTableElement").get_attribute("value")
print(themac1)



themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("DeviceMACAddress").text
print(themac1)



themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("DeviceMACAddress").get_attribute("value")
print(themac1)
```

I get a unable to locate element error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If id `DeviceMACAddress` is unique in HTML DOM, then the below code should work.

```
themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("DeviceMACAddress").text
print(themac1)
```

and since you've mentioned that it did not work, I would suggest to put some sleep or explicit waits like below :

```
themac1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "DeviceMACAddress"))).text
print(themac1)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If this also does not work, the possible cause would be :

1. **id is not unique**
2. it is in **iframe**
3. It not in **Selenium view port.**

**Update 1 :**

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("iframe xpath here")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, it didn't work. After more investigation, its in an iframe. How do i isolate its iframe?

Comment: You need to switch to iframe first. see above updated 1 code, after switching to iframe, you can `themac1 = browser.find_element_by_id("DeviceMACAddress").text
print(themac1)` or the other solution that I gave you.